# Trying to make a POST request, works with cURL, get a 403 when using Python requests

Tags: json, api, curl

I'm trying to get some JSON data from this API - https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries

This cURL request works fine and returns what is expected:

`curl -X POST "https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"searchText\":\"*:*\", \"fq\":[ \"totalPtoDays:[1 TO 99999]\", \"appFilingDate:[2005-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2005-12-31T23:59:59Z]\" ], \"fl\":\"*\", \"mm\":\"100%\", \"df\":\"patentTitle\", \"facet\":\"true\", \"sort\":\"applId asc\", \"start\":\"0\"}"`

I have this python script to do the same thing:

```
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
import json

url = "https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

data = json.dumps({
   "searchText":"*:*",
   "fq":[
      "totalPtoDays:[1 TO 99999]",
      "appFilingDate:[2005-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2005-12-31T23:59:59Z]"
   ],
   "fl":"*",
   "mm":"100%",
   "df":"patentTitle",
   "facet":"true",
   "sort":"applId asc",
   "start":"0"
})


resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(resp.status_code)
```

but it returns a 403 error code and the following response header:

```
   "Date":"Mon, 24 Oct 2022 16:13:58 GMT",
   "Content-Type":"text/html",
   "Content-Length":"919",
   "Connection":"keep-alive",
   "X-Cache":"Error from cloudfront",
   "Via":"1.1 d387fec28536c5aa92926c56363afe9a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
   "X-Amz-Cf-Pop":"LHR50-P8",
   "X-Amz-Cf-Id":"RMd69prehvXNAl97mo0qyFtuBIiY8r9liIxcQEmbdoBV1zwXLhirXA=="
```

I'm at quite a loss at what to do, because I really don't understand what my Python is missing to replicate the cURL request.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?    I do have some news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was interested in this.  I got an account with uspto.gov and acquired an access key. Their other API's work well.  But the PEDS API? I kept getting the Cloudflare Gateway Timeout 503 error.  While I was on their website, I looked into the PEDS API, I could not load any link to a https://ped.uspto.gov page.

I called them and they gave me an email address. I got this reply:

```
The PEDS API was taken down, because repeated data mining was bringing the entire PEDS System down.

The PEDS Team is working on a solution to fix the PEDS API, so that it can be re-enabled.
```

---

---

I tried it using PHP.
Cloudflare has been causing a lot of problems for curl.
I got a timeout. 
I may have gotten past the 403 Forbidden, but did not have credentials and so the server dropped the connection.

> An HTTP 504 status code (Gateway Timeout) indicates that when
> CloudFront forwarded a request to the origin (because the requested
> object wasn't in the edge cache), one of the following happened: The
> origin returned an HTTP 504 status code to CloudFront. The origin
> didn't respond before the request expired.

[image: Cloudflare 504.]

[AWS Cloudflare Curl Issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-504-gateway-timeout.html)
[bypassing CloudFlare 403](https://pixeljets.com/blog/scrape-ninja-bypassing-cloudflare-403-code-1020-errors/)
[How to Fix Error 403 Forbidden on Cloudflare](https://webpop.io/cloudflare/how-to-fix-error-403-forbidden-on-cloudflare/)
[403 Forbidden cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003014512-4xx-Client-Error-Why-am-I-getting-a-403-error-#code_403)

---

██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████

---

This is a conversion from you curl.
The Content-Type:application/data is added by default when you send JSON data.
I do not know about your `json_data.dump` or you putting the JSON in parentheses.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

json_data = {
    'searchText': '*:*',
    'fq': [
        'totalPtoDays:[1 TO 99999]',
        'appFilingDate:[2005-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2005-12-31T23:59:59Z]',
    ],
    'fl': '*',
    'mm': '100%',
    'df': 'patentTitle',
    'facet': 'true',
    'sort': 'applId asc',
    'start': '0',
}

response = requests.post('https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries', headers=headers, json=json_data)
```